# Install env-cmd on github

Tags: reactjs, github, github-actions, building-github-actions, env-cmd

I'm manually setting up the environment variable depending what build I'am using ( QA or PROD ) and I'm using github actions to deploy my qa build..
So change the script from `npm run build` to `env-cmd -f ./.env.qa node scripts/build.js`.
The problem is `env-cmd` is not installed on github and I can't seem to find the github action to install it. For now when it tries to build it says `env-cmd: not found`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you installed it before trying to call it? `npm install env-cmd` or `npm install -g env-cmd`.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd

Comment: I am trying to install it on github actions not on my computer

Comment: Yeah I understand - you can install it there, just make a workflow step that runs the `npm install`

Comment: Ahh I'm already doing the npm install before the build